# IE slowing down after updatepanel partial update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, updatepanel

I'm trying to place a user control inside an UpdatePanel.
When the control is displayed, **typing inside the TextBoxes** has a large delay while in IE (6 & 8). FireFox has an excellent performance. Not only typing, but also scrolling etc experience a large delay up to a few seconds.

The usercontrol(s) contain quite a lot of javascript functions that are re-registered using the `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock` or `RegisterStartupScript functions`.

Has anyone any ideas why typing becomes so very slow? I believe it has to do something with memory leaking due to the re-registration of the jQuery functions. But I'm unable to find the source of it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript written by yourself or others or part of a reliable framework?

Generic tips:
- reduce processes and function calls
- delegate events
- cache and reuse jQuery results (especially for IE) and only requery when you know the DOM changed.
- avoid recursion unless you know how to avoid all memory leak prone practises.
- Concerning form inputs, use 'focus' and 'blur' events rather then 'keypress' wherever you can.
- When using 'keypress' events, debounce, debounce, debounce! (google it)

Use:
- Firebug profiler to see which functions are called and how many times, this shows you what you need to reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestions. We're actually having all kind of javascript, my own, written by collegues and embedded in custom controls written by our framework team. I'll have a look at the delegate events and the caching (for everything outside the updatepanel).

Comment: Your suggestion for using Firebug profiler helped a lot. I didn't knew about this feature. We found code that looked like $('body').keypress(function(){});. This caused about 50 calls every time we typed something. Thanks again for the good advice.

Comment: $(body).keypress(..) is imo. an anti pattern for event delegation since it's a catch-all-always-firing listener. Bind listeners to the closest possible ancestor (ie. the form element to catch events inside a form, or the ul element to catch events of list items). Also, consider lazy-attaching event listeners to when they are needed rather then always onDomReady.